Is there a way to have any form in formbuilder send an email to the person after submission aka "thank you for your ..."?
Is there a way to have any form in formbuilder send an email to the person after submission aka "thank you for your ..."?
I know you can have a thank you page, but I want to send an email to the address - so when they do not get an email they know they provided the incorrect email.
I have tried some of the answers I have seen about this topic - some suggesting "activities" but I cannot see "activities" in my form builder.

You should be able to add "Activity" via the + at the top of the screen

But sending an Activity to the assignee is a pretty ugly affair. The other option is to see if there is a field that is having data added/modified and then use CiviRules and its associated email feature to send an email
